# Database being created but not being seeded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My local database is being created, correctly, but the  data isn't getting implemented (all data here has no meaning or value)

Anybody know why? Or how to fix it.

The Database Initializer:

```
public static class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(FranchiseContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if(context.menus.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        //MENU
        var imgMenu = new Menu[]
        {
            new Menu { ID = 0, Path = "~/images/menu_hamburger.jpg" },
            new Menu { ID = 1, Path = "~/images/menu_hamburger.jpg" },
            // etc
        };

        foreach (Menu m in imgMenu)
        {
            context.menus.Add(m);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
//a lot of code being skipped but doing the same
```

The context:

```
public class FranchiseContext : DbContext
{
    public FranchiseContext(DbContextOptions<FranchiseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Menu> menus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locaties> locaties { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Franchise> franchise { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Jobs> jobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Menu>().ToTable("Menu");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Locaties>().ToTable("Locaties");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Franchise>().ToTable("Franchise");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Jobs>().ToTable("Jobs");
    }
}
```

In Program.cs I initialize the database

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = BuildWebHost(args);

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<FranchiseContext>();
                DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }
```

And my appsettings.json

```
appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Stage
Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When debugging, does it ever reach `SaveChanges()`? Or e.g. does it exit at `Any()`?

Comment: @PeterB It exits at Any();
Edit: it doesn't exit at Any(), it only exits there if I change it to !context.menus.any()

Comment: @RobbeGregoire if instead of returning you debug to console when the "any" returns true to see what is already on the table ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez it never returns since the table is empty

Comment: if Any() returns true it means that is not empty

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez it only returns true when I reverse it by making it negative, so it's empty

Comment: Basically it runs the code, but doesn't insert it into the database, even though the INSERT INTO SQL command gets run in the events

Comment: any updates to this weird case ?